# Can't read from BlockingQueue in simple chat application

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have an issue with BlockingQueue (at least I think so). I'm writing up a simple chat application on Sockets, just in broadcast mode. I've got 2 public classes: Client and Server. Each of them has a private class: ClientHandler/ServerHandler. The Server has 2 threads: one that should accept and add to ArrayList clients instance and one for handling masseges. Client has one thread for displaying messages and an event to send messages to the server. Each client has it's own LinkedBlockingQueue, Server also has one. I've got no errors in my code, but can't see any messages:/

The code:

Server class:

```
public class Server {
    private final int serverPort = 23456;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    private ArrayList<ClientHandler> clientList = null;
     private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> messages;

    JFrame frame = null;
    JTextArea messageArea = null;

    public Server(){
        clientList = new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();
        messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        frame = new JFrame("Serwer");
        messageArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        messageArea.append("Uruchamianie serwera na porcie " + Integer.toString(serverPort) + "...\n");        
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            messageArea.append("Serwer aplikacji chat został uruchomiony.\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        Thread accept = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                        clientList.add(new ClientHandler(s));
                    } catch(IOException e){ 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        accept.setDaemon(true);
        accept.start();

        Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        System.out.println("wysylam");
                        String message = messages.take();
                        messageArea.append(message + "\n");
                        send(message);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){ }
                }
            }
        };

        messageHandling.setDaemon(true);
        messageHandling.start();
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            for(ClientHandler client : clientList){
                client.in.close();
                client.out.close();
                client.clientSocket.close();
            }
            serverSocket.close();
            messageArea.append("Serwer aplikacji chat został zatrzymany.\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void send(String message){
        for(ClientHandler client : clientList){
            client.out.write(message);
        }
    }

    private class ClientHandler{
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;

        ClientHandler(Socket socket){
            clientSocket = socket;
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                Thread read = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        while(true){
                            try{
                                String msg = in.readLine();
                                messages.put(msg);
                                System.out.println(msg);
                            }
                            catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){ 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                read.setDaemon(true);
                read.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
public Client(int id) {
        messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        this.id = id;
        frame = new JFrame("Klient");
        dataField = new JTextField(40);
        messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 60);

        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(dataField, "North");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Podaj nazwę użytkownika:");
        frame.setTitle(name);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", serverPort);
            server = new ServerHandler(socket);
            dataField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String message = dataField.getText();
                    dataField.setText("");
                    send(message);
                }
            });
            run();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        String message = messages.take();
                        messageArea.append(message + "\n");
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e){ }
                }
            }
        };

        messageHandling.setDaemon(true);
        messageHandling.start();
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ServerHandler {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        ServerHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            Thread read = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    while(true){
                        try{
                            String msg = in.readLine();
                            messages.put(msg);
                        }
                        catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
                    }
                }
            };

            read.setDaemon(true);
            read.start();
        }
    }

    private void send(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        server.out.write(msg);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

A simple test class:

```
class Main{
    private static final int clientsAmount = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        Client[] clients = new Client[clientsAmount];
        for (int i = 0; i < clientsAmount; i++){
            clients[i] = new Client(i);
        }

        server.start();

       // server.close();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, in your simple test class, do you ever send any messages?  You should if you want to see a result.

Comment: @markspace in test class I'm not sending anything, because I've got a simple GUI in Client class to do this. There is a dataField with an action listener attached to it, where I'm sarving sending messages.

Comment: Well, I think you need to break your code into smaller chunks so that it can be tested.  I'm having a hard time following the logic.  Try testing only the server, and try to test less than the whole thing.  Like try to just spawn a client handler, and let that read/write one socket.  Make the test actually send and receive data so you don't have to do it manually

Comment: Where is the code blocking at?  What steps have you taken so far to debug the issue?